# Generate smoother colormap for contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, colormap, contourf

My data set contains approximately thousands of values in four columns *X, Y, Z, error of Z* -

```
1.2351e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2417e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2483e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2549e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2615e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2681e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2746e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2812e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.2878e+00  -6.3115e-02 1.8186e+01  1.8186e+01
1.2944e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.3010e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.3075e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.3141e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
1.3207e+00  -6.3115e-02 0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
... ....
```

I want to plot these data using a contour plot, something like this-
(reference image)
[image: reference image]

I am using the following code -

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y, z, err = np.genfromtxt(r'dataset_gid.txt', unpack=True)


x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(x, y)
cont1 = plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, cmap='seismic')
plt.colorbar(cont1)
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following plot -

[image]

How can I generate a colorbar similar to the above image? I have created a gist for the dataset I am using [here](https://gist.github.com/frdayeen/b92027462675407288d18bbdc23e9c71#file-dataset_gid-txt).

**Update**

Using `scat=plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=3);plt.colorbar(scat)` gives me weird lines -

[image]

Using `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, levels=50)` looks better but the spots are not bright enough.

[image]

Is there a way to make the spots brighter like the reference image?

Comment: Have you tried the passing the `levels` `kwarg`? I.e. `plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, levels=50, cmap='seismic')`. That will tell matplotlib to use 50 colors, which will provide a smoother gradient.

Comment: `'seismic'` is a divergent colormap, not really appropriate for your data. Re the segmented colormap,  it's what you get if  you plot a contour plot, where discrete colors are used to represent what lies between two contour lines. I'd suggest a scatter plot with the standard colormap, or maybe `'Blues_r'`

Comment: Re using `tricontourf`, it's not needed as your data lies on a grid, 77×843×4

Comment: When I say scatter plot, I mean `scat=plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=3);plt.colorbar(scat)`

Comment: @jared I have added levels. It seems better. But is there a way to make the spots brighter?

Comment: @gboffi scatter plot introduced weird lines. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you shuffled through the likely looking [predefined colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html)  ? If not, you might want to design your own colormap, for which [this overview of color spaces](https://ericportis.com/posts/2024/okay-color-spaces/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A few preliminaries

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = lambda: plt.figure(layout='constrained')
d2 = lambda arr: arr.reshape(77, 843)
a_n_d = np.logical_and
```

read the data, find extremes

```
x, y, z, e = np.array([
    [float(x) for x in line.split()]
    for line in open('gist.txt').readlines()]).T

xlim = (x.min(), x.max())
ylim = (y.min(), y.max())
```

plot a scatter plot of all the data, the *"weird lines"*, ([OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143337/generate-smoother-colormap-for-contour-plot?noredirect=1#comment137765205_78143337)) are just the data points, that are all placed on a regular grid, loose in *x*-direction and tight in *y*-direction.

```
fig()
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=40, cmap='Blues')
plt.colorbar(scat)
```

[image]

Now, let;s plot a contour plot, with 3 levels

```
fig()
cont = plt.contour(d2(x), d2(y), d2(z), levels=[10, 40, 160], cmap='Blues', lw=0.2)
plt.colorbar(cont)
```

[image]

In my opinion, the contour plot is less informative than the scatter plot.

Finally, let's try a set of *selective* scatter plots, where we draw only the points whose *z* values are comprised in a different range for each subplot

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, layout='constrained')
for ax, ix in zip(axs.flat,
                  (z<100, a_n_d(z>=100, z<250), a_n_d(z>=250, z<500), z>500)):
    ax.set_xlim(xlim) ; ax.set_ylim(ylim)
    scat = ax.scatter(x[ix], y[ix], s=10, c=z[ix], cmap='Blues')
    plt.colorbar(scat, ax=ax)
```

[image]

In my opinion, this arrangement is the most informative.

The color scales are different in the different subplots, you can have the same scaling using `vmin=`, `vmax=` but, again IMO, it's better with different scales.

---

**Array Shape Clarification**

First, I looked at the factors of 64911

```shell
$ factor 64911
64911: 3 7 11 281
$
```

next I had a look into the data, the lines 1–77 have the same *y* value and different *x* values, the lines 78–154 have another, common *y* value and *the same* 77 *x* values of lines 1–77.

My conclusion was the data is given over a  (7·11)×(3·281) = 77×843 *x*–*y* grid.

Re your data, a lot of error values are equal to *z* value reported in the previous column, is this what you expect from your measurements/simulations?

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit confused about the reshape array. My data contains 64,911 rows and 4 columns. How do I know it needs to be reshaped as 77x843? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @aries0152 I tried to address your concern in an edit to my question, please see above.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer provides some valuable suggestions. I upvoted it. The reference image was plotted by me but using Origin. I am trying to move away from Origin and use Python instead. That's why I am trying to generate something similar to what I have. Not sure why ```contour``` in Python generates something different than what I had from ```contour plot``` from Origin.